# Creating your own Method?

Tags: java, methods

*I might have used the wrong word, so if I did, please tell me so I can correct it. I'm just going by what I think it would be called, based on what I gathered from the Java Hierarchy.

But here is my question:*

For this example, I will explain what I see, ask the question, and then provide an example. (I will be using the word `Method` because that's the word I think is appropriate, unless told otherwise)

Do you know how you can have a variable, and for the sake of this example, it's a `String`? Now for this string, you could use a method like `myString.setText("String");`, or `myString.equalsIgnoreCase(otherString);`.

Now, for my question, is it actually possible to create your own method?

For the sake of this example, let's say `myString.setText("Knife");`. Now since we know `myString` is a knife, could I create a method where I could call `myString` to see if it was equipped, or to make it equipped? For example: `myString.setEquipped(true);` and if I wanted to check if it was equipped or not, I could call `myString.getEquipped();`

*Am I using the word `Method` properly? And if my original question is possible, could we provide a small example?*

Thanks in advance for all your time and work.

Comment: You want to add new methods to the String class, is that it?

Comment: In that case, extend `java.lang.String`. That might get tricky though.

Comment: To the string class, or any other variable that I might need special functions for, yes, sir.

Comment: Your example "myString is a knife" is confusing - myString is a String, not a Knife.

Comment: @11684 You cannot extend String.

Comment: @11684 is it possible to show me an example, or point me to a link with details?

Comment: Normally, you would extend the exising class and add methods to your child class. However, String is final, so this is not possible. You could create a container class, but why exactly do you need to add a method to the String class?

Comment: String is `final`, you can't extend it.

Comment: since string is just an example and you have a class of your own which is extendable(i presume), you can just inherit and define your own methods. remember you can derive whats extendable or implementable not that which is final

Comment: -1.  Please Google "create your own method."  You get many Java articles on this.  From here you would learn what the word means and be able to ask a much more informed question, and possibly just have had your question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the basics of [object-oriented programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) as they are implemented in Java (and yes, "method" is correct.) You want to define an object with some methods that modify its internal state. For a very simple example:

```
public class MyObject {
    // Instance variables
    private String text;
    private boolean equipped;

    public MyObject() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    // setters
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public void setEquipped(boolean equipped) {
        this.equipped = equipped;
    }

    // getters
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
    public boolean isEquipped() {
        return this.equipped;
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.setEquipped(true);
        o.setText("Knife");
        System.out.println("Is 'o' equipped?");
        System.out.println(o.isEquipped());
        System.out.println("What is 'o'?");
        System.out.println(o.getText());
    }
}
```

You can't modify the `String` `class`, as others have said, because it is `final`. However, you can (and should!) define your own classes, with all the methods and objects that they need to do what they need to do. For instance, in the example you gave, you wanted to be able to set the object's `text` and then tell whether it is equipped. That suggested to me that you want a class where each instance of the class contains a `String` (`text`) and a `boolean` (`equipped`)

That's how I chose to write my example the way that I did: your object wants a "[has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)" relationship to both `String` and `boolean`. This is in contrast to an "[is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)" relationship, since it wouldn't make sense for your object to actually **be** either a `String` or a `boolean`.

However, it might make sense for this object to **be** a `Weapon`, for instance. In that case, you would want to define a `Weapon` class, and then [extend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) that class with a `Knife` class, a `Sword` class, and so on.

Comment: Its like you picked up the source of why I came to this question, and just answered any further questions I could have. Creating a weapon class was going to be the next question I asked and you took the extra step to cover that without knowing if I would actually need it to not. Thank you for the elegant example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,, you can do all that, but I suggest you use your IDE to generate these methods.
 e.g. If you have.

```
public class Item {
    private final String name;
    private boolean equiped;
}
```

Your IDE can generate these methods for you.

```
public class Item {
    private final String name;
    private boolean equiped;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEquiped() {
        return equiped;
    }

    public void setEquiped(boolean equiped) {
        this.equiped = equiped;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Item item = (Item) o;

        if (equiped != item.equiped) return false;
        return !(name != null ? !name.equals(item.name) : item.name != null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (equiped ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", equiped=" + equiped +
                '}';
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
Item knife = new Item("Knife");
knife.setEquiped(true);
System.out.println("Item is " + knife);
```

Comment: So for this example, instead of adding 'knife' to a `String`, I could just create a whole new class called `Knfie`? Then I could just say `Knife knife = new Knife();` and then manipulate it that way?

Comment: Correct.  In Java the solution to a problem often involves creating a custom class.  This is a bit strange as not all programming languages work this way.  The benefit is strict type checking, less error prone code and better performance. (It means more work for you though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Only via

1. reflection, which is not what you really want to do
2. Modifying the original source.  For most purposes you can't modify the source of `String`.

Then there's inheritance in which you derive a class and add methods.  Most classes you can, but `String` is not one of them as it is `final`.

Comment: Perfect. I did not know String was final though, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered.